# Increase my script performance Google Sheets Script

Tags: arrays, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a function that whenever I run the AppendRow script every row that does not have a dot (".") at the AY column, **an array with every information/column that I want** from that sheet will be transfered to my main sheet that has around **13k rows** atm.

Usually about 20-40 rows get pasted into the first sheet everyday and this script automatically re-arranges the columns to my main sheet.

**PROBLEM:**
The problem is that each row that gets appended to my main sheet takes around **8-15sec to get transfered** and sometimes I get this "exceeded-maximum-execution-time" error thats its really annoying.

***Is there any way to make my code run faster or maybe just a way to make the script run more than 5 minutes?***

```
function AppendRow() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var Sheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var ss2017 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
  var sheet2017 = ss2017.getSheetByName("2017");

  var lastSourceRow = Sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastSourceCol = Sheet.getLastColumn();

  var sourceRange = Sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastSourceRow, lastSourceCol);
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  var lenght = sourceData.length;
  //Logger.log(lenght);

  var time = new Date();
  time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+01:00", "dd/MM/yy, HH:mm:ss");


      for(i=5326;i<=lenght;i++) 
//my i=5326 is just cuz I had already
// information on my sheet that was transfered before this script existed
      {

        var columnAY = Sheet.getRange(i,51).getValue();
        var checkReservation = Sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();

           if(columnAY == ".")
           {
       }
       else
       {
      var B = Sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var F = Sheet.getRange(i,6).getValue();
      var E = Sheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
      var K = Sheet.getRange(i,11).getValue();
      var L = Sheet.getRange(i,12).getValue();
      var V = Sheet.getRange(i,22).getValue();
      var O = Sheet.getRange(i,15).getValue();
      var P = Sheet.getRange(i,16).getValue();
      var Q = Sheet.getRange(i,17).getValue();
      var AF = Sheet.getRange(i,32).getValue();
      var AG = Sheet.getRange(i,33).getValue();
      var N = Sheet.getRange(i,14).getValue();
      var AI = Sheet.getRange(i,35).getValue();
      var AB = Sheet.getRange(i,28).getValue();
      var AC = Sheet.getRange(i,29).getValue();   



      var array = ["",B,F,E,K,L,"",V,O,P,Q,AF,AG,"","",N,N,AI,"","",AB,AC,"","","","",time];

      sheet2017.appendRow(array);


       Sheet.getRange(i,51).setValue(".");


       }
  }
}
```

p.s.: I also have a menu in my spreadsheet to run the script every time i want to not sure if that is any relevant to the question :P

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My Menu')
      .addItem('Copy to 2017', 'AppendRow')
      .addToUi();
```

Every comment is appreciated !! :)

Comment: For users wanting to understand how performance bottlenecks occur in Google Apps Script, it's worth reading the [Best Practices Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices?hl=en#use_batch_operations) from Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit to having a bit of a problem figure out how my i's coordinated with your's but I think my columns are correct.  So check it out but this should run a bit faster.

```
function AppendRow() 
{
  var ss0=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
  var vA0=rg0.getValues();
  var ss1=SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sh1=ss1.getSheetByName('2017');
  var TimeStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
  for(i=5326;i<vA0.length;i++)
  {
    var columnAY=vA0[i][50];
    var checkReservation=vA0[i][1];
    if(vA0[i][50]!='.')
    {
      var B = vA0[i][1];//Sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var F = vA0[i][5];//Sheet.getRange(i,6).getValue();
      var E = vA0[i][4];//Sheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
      var K = vA0[i][10];//Sheet.getRange(i,11).getValue();
      var L = vA0[i][11];//Sheet.getRange(i,12).getValue();
      var V = vA0[i][21];//Sheet.getRange(i,22).getValue();
      var O = vA0[i][14];//Sheet.getRange(i,15).getValue();
      var P = vA0[i][15];//Sheet.getRange(i,16).getValue();
      var Q = vA0[i][16];//Sheet.getRange(i,17).getValue();
      var AF = vA0[i][31];//Sheet.getRange(i,32).getValue();
      var AG = vA0[i][32];//Sheet.getRange(i,33).getValue();
      var N = vA0[i][13];//Sheet.getRange(i,14).getValue();
      var AI = vA0[i][34];//Sheet.getRange(i,35).getValue();
      var AB = vA0[i][27];//Sheet.getRange(i,28).getValue();
      var AC = vA0[i][28];//Sheet.getRange(i,29).getValue();   
      var array = ["",B,F,E,K,L,"",V,O,P,Q,AF,AG,"","",N,N,AI,"","",AB,AC,"","","","",TimeStamp];
      sh1.appendRow(array);
      sh0.getRange(i+1,51).setValue(".");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution was really helpful, now each row takes between 4-8sec. Thank you, I really need to learn how you did this :) Idk if it is possible to make it even faster but im happy with this one already!

Comment: The basic idea is to avoid setValue and getValue and instead use getValues() and perform as many of your operations as possible from the array. Some are unavoidable so just minimize where possible.